# If I take a user supplied value as a function parameter, how do I make it a global variable?

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm writing a program that can riffle shuffle a given sequence (list l), m times. My function takes in the list l and the number m as inputs but Ive defined the shuffle itself for one shuffle and then used a for loop to do it m times. However, now the for loop does not take the user assigned value of m.

I'm a Python noob so it's likely I'm missing a simple thing. Ive tried using global m, to (re)define m within my function but either I dont know how to do it, or it doesn't seem to work.

```
def riffle_shuffle(l, global m):
    #global m goes here?
    r = np.random.binomial(len(l),0.5)
    sd1 = l[:r]
    d2 = l[r:]
    fl = []
    c = [sd2,sd1]
    l2 = sd2+sd1
    for i in range(1,len(l) + 1):
        x = [sd2,sd1]
        y = [(len(sd2))/(len(l) - i+1),(len(sd1))/(len(l) - i+1)] 
        a = choices(x,y)
        a1 = a[0][0]
        fl.append(a1)
        #Deck Split is c
        #Sub decks are',c
        #Probabilities are',y
        #Deck chosen is',a
        #fl
        if a1 in sd1:
            sd1.remove(a1)
        elif a1 in sd2:
            sd2.remove(a1)        
return fl,m       

for j in range(1,m+1):
  fl = riffle_shuffle(fl)

return fl
```

I've gotten errors that say m is not defined, invalid syntax, the following error message. I don't know what this last one means.

'maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison'

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I missed the for loop I'd mentioned in the description. It's up now sorry.

Comment: Global is rarely the best solution. How are you trying to use it?

Comment: What problem do you have, that you think would be solved by making `m` global?

Comment: "However, now the for loop does not take the user assigned value of m" - considering that `m` is used *literally nowhere* in the `for` loop or in any part of the function body other than the `return` statement, it's no surprise that `m` isn't affecting the loop in any way. Did you mean to use the value of `m` somewhere?

Comment: From what I understand, if I make m global, then until and unless the function is called again, the for loop I'm trying to run 'knows' the value of m? If there's some way for me to run the for loop without making m global that would work too.

Comment: Well, your question makes more sense with the second loop added, but now it's unclear why you want to have `riffle_shuffle` take `m` at all.

Comment: Consider a deck of cards, that need to be shuffling. As it stands, riffle_shuffle shuffles them once. I'd like a program that can shuffle the supplied sequence multiple times (m times, to be exact), by taking the number of times, m, as an argument

Answer (score 0):

So... You want method that do riffle shuffle m times, right?

There is some problems with your code :

First, `return` is outside of the function.

Second, you call your function in your function, without breaking condition : So the function will call the function, and that will call the function again, and again, and so on, until error occurs. That is `maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

Third, you have use `np.random.choice` like this : `np.random.choice(x, p=y)`. Otherwise, python don't know y is probabilities, and it will interpret it as second argument : size of the output. So error occurs here.

This might be the code you want to write :

```py
import numpy as np

def riffle_shuffle(l, m):
    if m == 0:
        return l
    else:
        fl = []
        r = np.random.binomial(len(l), 0.5)
        sd1 = l[:r]
        sd2 = l[r:]
        c = [sd2,sd1]
        l2 = sd2+sd1
        for i in range(1,len(l) + 1):
            x = [sd2,sd1]
            y = [(len(sd2))/(len(l) - i+1), (len(sd1))/(len(l) - i+1)] 
            a = np.random.choice(2, p=y)
            a = x[a]
            a1 = a[0]
            fl.append(a1)
            #Deck Split is c
            #Sub decks are',c
            #Probabilities are',y
            #Deck chosen is',a
            #fl

            if a1 in sd1:
                sd1.remove(a1)
            elif a1 in sd2:
                sd2.remove(a1) 
        fl = riffle_shuffle(fl, m - 1)

        return fl


a = riffle_shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3)
print(a)
#output : [5, 6, 1, 7, 4, 8, 2, 3] (can be changed)
```

As you did, I called the function 'recursively' - call function in function - with break condition.

In this way, you don't have to use global variable - using global variable is not good idea in most situation.

And, about your question(How can I make user-supplied value to global variable), you can do something like this.

```py
a = 0
def foo(m):
    global a
    a = m
    #and your code here...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There's a couple of things that I don't understand though. Firstly, why would I need to change how the deck is split wrt r being chosen from n= (len(l) - 1). With using random.choices so if I used the program as it is, but excluding m (ie for just one shuffle) it seems to work okay. In your answer, np.random,choices(x,y), I'm not sure what it means if x =2 ? I will try this code out regardless and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: First argument of `np.random.choice` is int or 1D array-like, but `x` is 2D array. So I change code like this : first get `0` or `1` use `np.random.choice(2, p=y)`. If int is given as first argument,(let's say : 2) it is simmilar with `np.random.choise([0, 1], p=y)` [see this link for help](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). So I get 0 or 1 with y's probability, and then use it to index `x`.

Comment: and `n = (len(l) - 1)` was my mistake. I'll fix it right now.